# Angular UI Bootstrap carousel with angular-nvd3 chart

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, nvd3.js

i am using Angular UI Bootstrap carousel with angular-nvd3 chart and on the first slide the chart displays fine but the resto of the slides the chart is horizontally squeezed. is there a way to fix this problem?

```
<carousel interval="5000">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in [1,2,3,4,5]" >
        <nvd3 options="sva.options" data="sva.data"></nvd3>
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

here is the code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UhdoiYRu2GezxGgLThAv?p=preview)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, while i was trying to have gridster into carousel and charts kendo into that gridster.
i finally had it resolved by refreshing the binding of the chart based on the current active slide.

put a watch on the current scope and check which slide is active and rebind the data of the chart.